# How to keep JTable custom renderer looks on window resize?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, window-resize, tablecellrenderer

I have a JTable inside my Java application and applied to it there is a custom renderer that changes the background color of the last row of the table. Like this:

[image]

I achieve that with the following code for the custom renderer:

```
table.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new DefaultTableCellRenderer(){
    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table,
            Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int col) {
                
        super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected,
                                            hasFocus, row, col);
                
        String status = (String)table.getModel().getValueAt(row, 0);
        if ("Total".equals(status)) {
            setBackground(Color.GRAY);
            setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        } 
                
        this.setHorizontalAlignment(CENTER);
        return this;
    }
});
```

However, when I resize the window, it looks like this:

[image]

To get it back to normal I have to clear the table and add the items again, what should I do in order to keep the table look when resizing? Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You forgot the `else` block to set the colors back:

```
if ("Total".equals(status)) {
    setBackground(Color.GRAY);
    setForeground(Color.WHITE);
} else {
    // set colors back to the default settings
    setBackground(null);
    setForeground(null);
}
```

Otherwise the renderer remains "set" and will color all cells gray/white. Think of a renderer like a rubber stamp that is used to stamp out a lot of the same thing. If you change it's colors and don't change them back, the stamp is "stuck" in color mode.

Comment: Thank you that worked! I'll accept your answer in 5 minutes because stack overflow is not allowing me to accept it right now.

Comment: @AlexandreKrabbe: first have a critical look at camickr's always excellent suggestions. 1+ up-vote to his answer from me.

Answer (score 3):

In reality you should not be storing String data for your "Quantity" and "Price" columns. Instead you should be storing Integer and Double values. So this would mean you would need to create 3 custom renderers.

Another option is to override the `prepareRenderer(...)` method of the JTable to set the background color.

Check out out [Table Row Rendering](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/table-row-rendering/) for more information and an example of this approach.

Comment: Thank you for the info, I'll take a look into it.